# How do I get the ID of an Element

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

```
<div id="block_msg" style="width:250px;border: solid 1px red;margin: 15px">

<div id="text_msg1">111текст111</div>

<input type="submit" onclick="clickon(**<<<HERE I WANT SEE DIV ID TEXT_MSG1>>>**)" value="Добавить">

</div>
```

How  can I get `id="text_msg1"` and put it into `onclick`? How?

Comment: `this.id`, ID's are **unique** !!!

Comment: Do you want to the ID of the preceding `div` element? Or what is the relation between the `input` and the `div` element? What do you want to do with the ID?

Comment: yes, preceding! this line: 
<div id="text_msg1">111текст111</div>

Comment: this what i what next: <script>
 function clickon(id_num)
{
 
var copyFrom = document.getElementById(id_num)
var copyTo = document.getElementById('createBlock')


var newSelect = copyFrom.cloneNode(true)
copyTo.appendChild(newSelect)
}
</script>

Comment: Then you actually don't need the ID... you just need a reference to the element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is the current object, you can than look at the parent and find the divs. This solution is hacky since changing the layout means it will break.

```
onclick="clickon(this)"
```

and

```
function clickon(btn) {
    var wrappingDiv = btn.parentNode;
    var childrenDivs = wrappingDiv.getElementsByTagName("div");
    alert(childrenDivs[0].innerHTML);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M5w8H/1/)

It would be better to have a class on the div and look for that class.

Comment: sorry, now i detele id from input. this.id work with id in input

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the previous element sibling, traverse the DOM until you find it:

```
function get_previous_element_sibling(element) {
    var prev = element.previousSibling;

    while (prev && prev.nodeType !== 1) {
        prev = prev.previousSibling;
    }

    return prev;
}
```

Then you can get the previous sibling with:

```
get_previous_element_sibling(this)
```

and its ID with

```
get_previous_element_sibling(this).id
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment `yes, preceding! this line` will not work with IE8 and lower because of `previousElementSibling`

```
<input type="submit" onclick="clickon(this.previousElementSibling.id)" value="Добавить">
```

or using jQuery for cross browser support

```
<input type="submit" onclick="clickon($(this).prev().attr('id'))" value="Добавить">
```

Comment: You should at least mention that `previousElementSibling` is not supported in IE8 or earlier.

Comment: Thanks Felix, really have doubts about it that's why provided jQuery alternative